# Action of a Lie group on a coset of its subgroup

Tags: lie-groups, group-actions

I am a physicist, so sorry for the lack of rigor. It is well known that a (say compact) Lie group $G$ acts naturally by left multiplication on the coset space $G/H$ where $H\subset G$ is its (Lie) subgroup. Suppose now that $\tilde G$ is a subgroup of $G$ and define $\tilde H=H\cap\tilde G$. We can assume (this is the case that I am actually interested in) that $\tilde G$ is a centralizer of a given one-parameter subgroup of $G$. How, and under what conditions, can one define a (transitive) action of $G$ on the coset space $\tilde G/\tilde H$?

Comment: Regarding terminology, $G/H$ and $\tilde{G}/\tilde{H}$ are (left) coset spaces, not cosets. The points of these spaces are cosets (e.g. for $g\in G$, $gH$ is a coset, an element of $G/H$).

Comment: @KeenanKidwell Thanks for pointing this out! I fixed the text; hope that now the terminology is correct and the question is clear.